# how to do theme intergate in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, magento2.3, integration

I downloaded a theme using this [link](https://themehunt.com/item/1527109-darklook-e-commerce-bootstrap-responcive-template)

How to used CSS js HTML same theme show in Magento 2.3 frontend side so please tell me what to do in **theme integration**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a theme manually

To install a theme manually, you must have the theme’s code, either in a compressed archive or in a directory structure similar to the following:

```
<VendorName>
├── composer.json
  ├── etc
  │   └── view.xml
  ├── media
  ├── registration.php
  ├── theme.xml
  └── web
      ├── css
      │   └── source
      ├── fonts
      ├── images
      └── js
```

To install a theme manually:

Copy the theme’s code under /app/design/frontend for a storefront theme. Verify that the top-level directory is ; otherwise, the theme will not install properly.

For example:

> cp -r ExampleTheme /app/design/frontend

Confirm the theme copied to the correct place.

> Storefront theme: ls /app/design/frontend

Run the below commands to deploy your theme files

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade // to install a theme to database
php bin/magento s:s:d -f // deploy theme into pub/static
php bin/magento cache:clean
chmod -R 777 pub/static/* var/* generated/*
```

**A sample follows:**

Log in to the Magento Admin.

> Click Content > Design > Themes.

The theme displays in the right pane. Configure it to your store and see it up in frontend.

Refer this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/howtos/custom-theme.html)

Comment: I want to integrate theme in front end so please guide me. I want to integrate that theme which was given in that link. I have already download a theme from that link. but I don't know how to integrate that in magento 2.3

Comment: Updated it's only for frontend

Comment: For more specific in the sense give me your theme path wherever it is so I can assist you exactly.

Comment: Sir i want to integrate this theme https://themehunt.com/item/1527109-darklook-e-commerce-bootstrap-responcive-template in magento 2

Comment: It's not an magento theme so just like that you can't integrated and it won't work. Search for any magento theme and do the above steps then it will work and create a new theme @sannikalariya

Comment: Is there any way to integrate this theme I want integrate this theme only .

Comment: No it requires know some knowledge in desining and without creating a theme you won't get this design up in front. Got it

Comment: I would suggest you to create a theme and integrate this design into your theme. That would work out. thanks

Comment: ok Thank you for this guides @Prathap Gunasekaran

Comment: and to create a theme follow this guide would help you anyway https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html