# while installing custom theme.. I have an issue

Tags: magento2.2

**frontend/magento luma already exists..**
I have installed a Magento theme but could not see Homepage block for this theme 2

Comment: Read this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267852/how-to-do-theme-intergate-in-magento-2-3/267896#267896